# Prisma/Typescript: how to extend client?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, prisma

I implemented such class:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

export type NotStartsWith<
  S,
  Prefix extends string,
> = S extends `${Prefix}${infer _X}` ? never : S;

export class DatabaseService extends PrismaClient {
  async $findPaginated<
    M extends NotStartsWith<keyof DatabaseService, '$'>,
    A extends Parameters<DatabaseService[M]['findMany']>[0],
  >(model: M, args?: A) {
    const data = await this[model].findMany(args);
    return {
      page: 1,
      results: data,
      total: 1,
      totalPages: 1,
    };
  }
}
```

Let's assume I have models `post` and `user`.

The real implementation is not important. But typescript gives me this error on the `findMany` call:

`This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type 'x | y | z' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.`

I think it means that somehow I could call the `findMany` of `user` with arguments of `post`. But it is not possible since it is all well typed. If I change to `(this[model] as any)` to compile and type my new function with first argument `post`, the second argument's properties are correctly autocompleted for the model `post`.

So I don't get why I can't fully type my function.

Also, this is not an optimal extension for Prisma. Ideally I'd like to add typings to a *very* generic interface (findMany, findUnique etc.) that all models' use, and then add my function to all models at runtime. But that's not how Prisma generate types.

Comment: Your reasoning is a close, but it's actually because TypeScript cannot (or does not) associate the type of `A` to `M` yet, so it can't actually check if `A` matches `M` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to add the method of prisma client in Custom models.

Custom models:

```
class Users {
   constructor(private readonly prismaUser: PrismaClient['user']) {}

   //Signup a new user
   async signup(data: Signup): Promise<User> {
     // do some custom validation...
     return this. prismaUser. create({ data })
   }
}
```

Custom models document: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/custom-models

Comment: Or add custom methods to your models: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions/model